# comutil.cpp not found error, where can i find this file?

Tags: c++, sql-server, com, ado

I'm using ado to connect my c++ project to database. So when I'm making connection to SQL-Server and than open the connection I get such kind of error comutil.cpp not found but only if I use `step into(F11)` during debugging but if I use `step over(F10)` there is not error and continue running.

I have searched my computer and have not been able to find the file anywhere.
Should I install comutil.cpp source code or file?

p.s I don't have error until connection execute.(error is: `DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.`) also when connection opens but it also get nothing as value `<Information not available, no symbols loaded for msado15.dll>` and is this related to comutil.cpp? If not how can I execute my connection?

I've been wracking my brain over and over trying to find a solution for this, but does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

```
//TESTHR Function which check if HRESULT is okay or not
_ConnectionPtr pConnection;
_RecordsetPtr pRecordset;
_CommandPtr pCommand;

TESTHR(CoInitialize(NULL));

TESTHR(pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection)));
_bstr_t strCon(_T("ADOSQL"));
TESTHR(pConnection->Open(strCon, "", "", adOpenForwardOnly));

TESTHR(hr = pCommand.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command)));

_bstr_t InsertQuery(_T("Insert Into TestTB(AccountID, Balance) Values(@AccountID, @Balance)"));

pCommand->ActiveConnection = pConnection;
pCommand->CommandText = InsertQuery;
pCommand->CommandType = adCmdText;

TESTHR(pRecordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset)));
hr = pRecordset->Open(SQLQuery, pConnection.GetInterfacePtr(), adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText);
//-------------
//some operations
//-------------

pConnection->Execute(InsertQuery, vRecordsAffected, adCmdText); //here error occures
pRecordset->Close();
pConnection->Close();
CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: Did you link against comsuppw.lib?

Comment: no, what is that or how can i do that? is there any documentation?

Comment: You are trying to step into the `comutil` source code but it is unlikely that the error lies there. Instead of focusing on the problem on how to debug `comutil` or other Microsoft provided software you should probably look into your code. The connection string that you are using does not look like an ADO connection string. Maybe this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/activex-data-objects/create-an-ado-connection-string

Comment: PS: If you don't add @<name> to comments responding to a person then that person may not get a notification in their Inbox.

Comment: @J.R. i made it by ODBC Data Sources application ( because when i use full path of connection string it goes to an error), that connects correctly, i checked it from SQL server profiler. but maybe today i found something to execute command,i need to import "msadox.dll", i dont know exectly. am i right?

Comment: I suspect that is nothing to do with any DLL import but I'm guessing. There are some discussions on SO around the 'Multiple-step' error and how to approach it; maybe you can find something useful there.

Comment: @J.R i dont understand exactly what is SO or Multiple-step error?

Comment: @GiorgiGogenia SO = stackoverflow and the multiple-step error is the error that you have reported.

Comment: thank you. i will search for it